# Why does this question exist twice? Stack Exchange Multiverse?

Tags: support, migration

I just answered the question [What's the point of initializing a variable with the same value twice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122378/whats-the-point-of-initializing-a-variable-with-the-same-value-twice) here on Programmers.

I was going to answer it anyway, then saw that Morons suggested it be migrated to StackOverflow.  I agreed, so I added my migration vote.  Then I answered the question.

Now, it exists on StackOverflow as well, and my answer exists in two different places.  You can see from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8316463/revisions) that it was migrated, but it doesn't say by whom.

And, it's still open on Programmers.  Thankfully, Mark Trapp has locked it in the mean time.  But, I don't really know what happened - even after the migration happened, I still saw "close(2)" in the question links.

Comment: **To the migraters:** *Please don't use migration as a way to dispose of questions you don't like.* If you don't like the question, **vote to close it** instead of dumping it onto another site.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what gives you an indication that migration was being used that way?

Comment: I personally think it's a better fit for SO, but generally speaking, if it's on-topic on the originating site, it should stay there, and not be migrated somewhere else.

Comment: I agree with that point, thanks for the clarification Robert.

Comment: Really, you shouldn't call your fellow users "Morons".  Remember, the [faq#benice] tells us to "be nice".

Answer (score 4):

This question has caused a bit of an adverse reaction here: within 5 or so minutes of being asked, it was migrated to Stack Overflow before I could short circuit the migration and settle the dispute here.

I cleared the migration history, which removed the trace of the migration from the question and reopened it. This didn't remove the migrated version on Stack Overflow, which now exists separately.

Within a minute or two of doing that, it gained another 3 migrate votes to Stack Overflow, which prompted my lock: there's no point in migrating the question twice.

The Stack Overflow moderators there have opted not to delete this artifact because they feel it's just barely on-topic for Stack Overflow. So what we're left with is the functional equivalent of a cross-post that you happened to answer on both sites.

Edit: I've opened up a [new question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2608/are-why-is-x-code-snippet-done-this-way-questions-on-topic) to discuss the dispute.